# Scrollback lines on SSH session with Ubuntu 22 minimal server

Tags: server, bash, ssh

I've installed a new minimal Ubuntu 22 server on hardware and am now SSH'ing to it from a local network PC - however I note that the output in the ssh window (Terminal on MacBook Pro) is limited to a single screen of information, and I can't scroll back to view extended output.

Is it possible to see more than one screen worth of information?

Edit: I have another Ubuntu 22 server box, which I can log into via the same program on the Mac and it doesn't display this behaviour. So it looks like something unique to this newer server.

Comment: AFAIK the scollback buffer is a feature of your *local terminal* - so see for example [Limit the number of scrollback rows in Terminal on Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/terminal/trml15233/mac) and/or [Enable unlimited scrollback with iTerm2](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/368613/enable-unlimited-scrollback-with-iterm2)

Comment: Are you using a terminal multiplexer on the server like `tmux` or `byobu` or `GNU`'s `screen`? These maintain their own scrollback independent of the client side terminal, so in many cases, the local output always remains the height of the local window.